# SSH into Home Assistant instance from anywhere

Tags: raspberry-pi, home-assistant, remote-access

So I have Home Assistant running on an RPi-4. I have the instance running locally but I also have the cloud service through Nabo Casa. I have a sub-domain through my domain from google domain that I can access the home assistant UI through the browser remotely with the credentials.

I wanted to know if I can setup the Home Assistant in a way where I can SSH into the instance and access the files remotely. I have samba share add-on added but I can only access it if I am on the same network. I tried to SSH into the instance using `ssh username@sub-domain -p 22222` but it did not resolve and timed out.

Comment: A few hints: port forwarding, dyndns, ngrok

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing it:

1. VPN to your home router/firewall. Many brands has included a VPN feature in their home routers/firewalls
2. Open a hole in the firewall to your Raspberry Pi4 for a SSH port. This is also called port forwarding and instructions for doing it can be found in your home router/Firewall manual.

Both ways need Dynamic DNS and the reason is that your IP address allocate via DHCP from your ISP (Internet Service Provider) can change.

And by installing a free DynDNS client on your Raspberry Pi or this feature can also be available in your home router/Firewall.

The DynDNS concept is that you get a hostname from a free DynDNS service that you report your current IP to the DynDNS service.